# IBM Blockchain Platform V2, API and chaincodes

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

IBM Blockchain Platform V1 has(had) a nice API to interact with the blockchain itself. Here is the link to the swagger: https://ibp-sp.eu-gb.ibm-blockchain-5-prod.cloud.ibm.com/api-docs/

Among others, we could install and instantiate chaincodes (thus, we could have some kind of automation for chaincode deployment).

However, based on [this](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/blockchain?) documentation for IBM Blockchain Platform V2, there is not API to install/instantiate chaincode. We can only manage the network.

So my questions are:

- Is it not possible to manage chaincodes via API with IBP2?
- If it is possible, where is the documentation?
- If it is not possible, why has it been removed and it it planed to be added in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It **is** possible to manage chaincodes via API in IBP2.

According to [the documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/blockchain) that you posted above, there is a big yellow block that says **Important**: `Also, you can use the Fabric Node SDK or peer CLI commands to install and instantiate smart contracts.`

This means that you can use the Hyperledger Fabric APIs to install / instantiate your chaincode.

For example, one of my peers that is running in IBM Blockchain platform has the following URL, according to the connection profile:

`grpcs://cd8945b468274f94b24b0dce0b0d6583-peer443d9f.horea-blockchainbean2-ap.sjc03.containers.appdomain.cloud:7051`

Thus, to install a chaincode on this peer, we would do the following command:

`CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=grpcs://cd8945b468274f94b24b0dce0b0d6583-peer443d9f.horea-blockchainbean2-ap.sjc03.containers.appdomain.cloud:7051 peer chaincode install -n mycc -p github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02 -v v0`

Note that we have to do this command from inside the CLI container. So before we run this command we would have to do `docker exec -it cli bash`. You can see the documentation [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install_instantiate.html#install-the-chaincode-on-peer0-from-the-remote-cli)